# How to access state from an handler on nextjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, next.js

I have a handler defined by the custom app (`_app`), hook to the `routeChangeStart` event.

The handler should analyze the new path and store some result at state variable.
The handler is a class member, yet it throws the error:

> Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): this is undefined

Here the code:

```
import App from 'next/app';
import Router from 'next/router'
import { withRouter } from 'next/router'
import MyAppContext from '~/components/MyAppContext';


class MyApp extends App {

    state = {
      language: null
    };

    getCurrentLanguage(url){
        ...
    }

    handleRouteChange(url){
      console.log('App is changing to: ', url)
      this.setState (  //throws: Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): this is undefined
         {language: this.getCurrentLanguage(url)}
      )
    }
    componentDidMount = () => {

      this.setState({language: this.getCurrentLanguage()})
        Router.events.on('routeChangeStart', this.handleRouteChange)
      };

    render() {
      const { Component, pageProps } = this.props;

      return (
        <MyAppContext.Provider value={{ language: this.state.language }}>
          <Component {...pageProps} />
        </MyAppContext.Provider>
      );
    }
  }

export default withRouter(MyApp)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function is a class member, but `this` is dependent on the context of where the function is **called** not **declared**. You are passing the function reference to the listener which will call it from somewhere else, meaning `this` will not be referring to the class anymore.

You'll have to either bind it to `this` manually, or make it an arrow function.

```js
handleRouteChange = (url) => {

// or

Router.events.on('routeChangeStart', this.handleRouteChange.bind(this))
```